# Why does codeigniter mysql return an empty array

Tags: mysql, codeigniter

In the following AnimalSpecies is a table with one column named Values.  I wish to retrieve the elements of this column as an array.  Very basic!  How come the following returns an empty array?  I've tried many things and when I just do mysql directly using

SELECT `Values` FROM `AnimalSpecies` WHERE 1

I seem to get the right thing.

Model:

```
//retrieve dropdown options
public function get_options($table) {

    $this->db->select('*');
    $this->db->from($table);
    //$this->db->where('Options');

    $query = $this->db->get();
    //print_r($query);

    if ( $query->num_rows() > 0 )
    {
        $data = $query->row_array();
        print_r($this->db->last_query());die();
        return $data;
    }
}
```

Controller:

```
public function upload_page()
{
        $this->load->model('data_model');
        $species = $this->data_model->get_options("AnimalSpecies");
```

}

I've figured out how to get the "Options" column values as an array, though I have to strip off parts of the mysql output and so it's a bit clumsy.  Without the for loop I get numeric indices for each of the column values.

```
public function get_options($table) {

    $this->db->select('*');
    $this->db->from($table);

    $query = $this->db->get();

    if ( $query->num_rows() > 0 )
    {
        $data = $query->result_array();

        for ($i=0; $i < count($data); $i++)
        {
            $options_array[] = $data[$i]['Options'];
        }

        return $options_array;
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried `print_r()` on the `$query` result (or `var_dump()`) before processing the `row_array()` to see what you get? Also, try displaying the actual query executed by adding `print_r($this->db->last_query());die();` before the return statement.

Comment: i strongly suggest you always do a $query->num_rows() > 0 test before processing data unless you are absolutely certain there will be at least one row

Comment: print_r gives CI_DB_mysql_result Object ( [conn_id] => Resource id #31 [result_id] => Resource id #37 [result_array] => Array ( ) [result_object] => Array ( ) [custom_result_object] => Array ( ) [current_row] => 0 [num_rows] => 7 [row_data] => ) arrayarray(1) { ["Options"]=> string(0) "" }

Comment: And the result of print_r($this->db->last_query());die(); before the return is is SELECT * FROM (`AnimalSpecies`).  It looks like it's giving me a bunch of stuff in addition to the values of the Options column.  How do I just get those values?  Thanks for your help, BTW!

Comment: I'm editing the code to reflect my current implementation....

Answer (score 0):

This should do it (judging by your last comment):

```
public function get_options($table) {
    return $this->db->select('Options')
    ->get($table)
    ->row_array();
}
```

It will return false if no data is found, otherwise, you'll get an array.

If you need just the options value, you can use:

```
public function get_options($table) {
    return $this->db->select('Options')
    ->get($table)
    ->row()
    ->Options;
}
```

This will return whatever the value of Options is in the first row, but it might throw an error if no rows are found.

Comment: Thanks for your nifty response!  It's cleaner than my current soln, but it doesn't quite work.  Your forst soln only returns the first row of the "Options" column.  I need to return all the "Options" columns as an array.  The way I'm doing it is a bit clumsy, but works and I've included it in the above edit.

Comment: I see, then you need to use `result_array()` instead of `row_array()` (just the first example, this won't work with the second one)